# C# performing a task every hour

Tags: c#, timer

I have a CSV importer tool I use at my company that imports 10-20k records at a time but it can take a couple hours, the issue is that the application is connecting to an API that has an OAuth token that expires after an hour.

to me this sounds like a job for timer, but the actual code that imports and needs the oauth token are in modules since each vendor I have to upload have their own mappings to the api we use.

so I need to programmatically need to see if 3590 seconds (or 50 minutes) has passed so that I can refresh my OAuth token.

does anyone know how I can do this? if timer is not the best way to go, what way would you suggest?

it'd be nice if timer has an Elapsed property I could access from my other objects (like I can with background worker).

Comment: Instead of gathering all 10-20k records at once, grab 500 at a time, 40 times, all at once, using async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just make it part of your processing loop:

```
{
    DateTime lastReset = DateTime.Min;
    TimeSpan resetInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50);

    foreach (var whatever in enumerable)
    {
        if ((DateTime.Now - lastReset) > resetInterval)
        {
            ResetAuthToken();
            lastReset = DateTime.Now;
        }
        ProcessWhatever();
    }
}
```

Comment: thats the way I want to go actually.

Comment: I used your method to meet my demand, it was the closest to what I wanted and the one with the least amount of headache to it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you can use the timer's elapsed event. This will be triggered based on the interval may be 50 minutes etc, which you can read from the configuration file of the windows service.

Then in the timer interval, you can just update a global variable [property] with the Auth token that will be used for the subsequent API calls.

In case you just want to keep the session alive, you can just refresh the token as itmse86 said. However, the timer elapsed event will come handy for you.

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)